# Javascipt Replace all characters with underscore except the first word

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all the characters in a string with underscore except for the first word, but my code replaces all the characters with an underscore.

Expected result: Hello ___ __ _________

```js
var regex = /[a-z0-9,.':!?"]/gi;
var str = "Hello I'm an astronaut";
console.log(str.replace(regex, "_"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to achieve it by just using regex though

```js
var regex = /(^\S*\s*)?\S/gm;
var str = "Hello I'm an astronaut";
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$1_"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a split and regex approach here:

```js
var str = "Hello I'm an astronaut";
var first = str.substr(0, str.indexOf(' '));                      // finds first word
var rest = str.substr(str.indexOf(' ') + 1).replace(/\S/g, "_");  // find other words
console.log(first + " " + rest);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var regex = /[a-z0-9,.':!?"]/gi;
var str = "Hello I'm an astronaut";
console.log(str.substr(0,str.indexOf(' ')) +str.substr(str.indexOf(' ')).replace(regex, "_"));
```

Comment: He beat me to it by 40 seconds, use theirs @Tim's

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using a lookbehind for the browsers that [support it](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind):

```
(?<=^\S+\s.*)\S
```

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is at the left is

  - `^\S+\s.*` Match 1+ non whitespace chars followed by a whitspace char at the start of the string
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `\S` Match a single non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QUPKma/1)

```js
var regex = /(?<=^\S+\s.*)\S/g;
var str = "Hello I'm an astronaut";
console.log(str.replace(regex, "_"));
```

Or using a capture group for the part that you want to keep, and replace the matches with an underscore:

```
^(\S+)|\S
```

- `^(\S+)` Start of the string, capture 1+ non whitespace chars in **group 1** (Denoted by `g1` in the example code
- `|` Or
- `\S` Match a single non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MHYchM/1)

```js
var regex = /^(\S+)|\S/g;
var str = "Hello I'm an astronaut";
console.log(str.replace(regex, (m, g1) => g1 ? g1 : "_"));
```